# ESP32 access point with an ENC28J60 ethernet module

Tags: esp32, wifi, ethernet

Does anyone know if the following is possible? Any advice would be much appreciated.

I am programming an Ethernet connected Arduino to be a webserver. What would be ideal is a small portable "router" so I can take the whole test setup and my laptop without depending on my home/company network.

My idea:

- Set up an ESP32 as an access point
- Connect an ENC28J60 module to it

I hope:

- My laptop can connect to the ESP over WiFi (status: done)
- My board can connect over UTP
- They both get IP addresses
- I can test the Arduino webserver from my laptop

What I found is that I could use the [Ethercard for ESP32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY0Ht.jpg) or the [EthernetENC][2] libraries.

I've been trying with EthernetENC, but no luck. Is this even possible?

[image]

This is my minimal code for the ESP32 so far:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <EthernetENC.h>

const char* ssid = "ESP32router01";
const char* pass = "01234567";          // At least 8 characters

void setup() { 
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, pass);
  Ethernet.init(5);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: remove the Arduino and the ENC28J60 from the project

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/adapter-for-ethernet-shield-to-communicate-on-wifi/529679/3

Comment: esp8266 Arduino supports routing between network interfaces and supports enc28j60 as network interface in WiFi library. STA and SofftAP are the network interfaces you know. I don't know if it supports routing for the 'new' network interlaces

Comment: @Juraj : Thanks, the TL-WR702N would be the easy/convenient way, I'll consider that. But I also have an ESP8266  at hand so I can explore your suggestion.

Comment: I'm still planning on doing this project and have found: https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater#enc28j60-ethernet-support - This library supports an ENC28J60 ethener adapter so that's what I'll be trying, I don't know when but I'll try to post my findings.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have a similar problem.